# How can I use node-mocks-http when mocking the AWS SDK?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-mock, node-mocks-http

I've got an existing working test that is testing a route in an Express app (trimmed code):

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk-mock');
const AWS_SDK = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.setSDKInstance(AWS_SDK);

...

  before(() => { 
    sendEmailMock = sinon.stub().callsArgWith(1, null, 'All is well');
    AWS.mock('SES', 'sendEmail', sendEmailMock);
    server = rewire('../../../..');

...

  describe('POST:/feedback', () => { 
    it('Returns 200 with a fully formed request', (done) => {

      request(app)
        .post('/gethelp/api/v1/feedback')
        .send({
          thumbsUp: 'true',
          title: 'Abcdef ghi',
          url: 'http://google.com',
          comments: 'lkajsdj  lkajsdkjf aslkjdfa asjdflasjd lkfj',
        })
        .expect(200, () => {
          const args = sendEmailMock.args[0][0];
          ... etc
```

This is a working test. But I need to refactor it to not use the full server (because it's doing some integration stuff on startup). So I'm bringing in `node-mocks-http`:

```
const httpMocks = require('node-mocks-http');
const feedbackRouteHandler = require('./feedback');

...

 before(() => {
    sendEmailMock = sinon.stub().callsArgWith(1, null, 'All is well');
    AWS.mock('SES', 'sendEmail', sendEmailMock);
  });

... 

     const mockRequest = httpMocks.createRequest({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/gethelp/api/v1/feedback',
        body: {
          thumbsUp: 'true',
          title: 'Abcdef ghi',
          url: 'http://google.com',
          comments: 'lkajsdj  lkajsdkjf aslkjdfa asjdflasjd lkfj',
        },
      });

      const mockResponse = httpMocks.createResponse();

      feedbackRouteHandler(mockRequest, mockResponse);

      expect(mockResponse.statusCode).to.equal(200);

      expect(sendEmailMock.args).to.exist;
```

The problem is that adding in `node-mocks-http` appears to have broken the mocking of the AWS SDK. When `sendEmail` is hit it's hitting the actual AWS SDK, not the mocked version. It was hitting the mocked version in the previous version of the test.

How can I use `node-mocks-http` with `aws-sdk-mock`?